# Angular hide header for all following directories

Tags: angular, url, routes, angular-ng-if

I am currently hiding my header by doing the following:

`*ngIf="router.url != '/admin'`

This is working as expected, the problem is... I also want to hide the header in /admin/home and others.

Considering I want to hide the header on all URL's following /admin, what would be the best approach (without having to write them all out manually)?

Comment: quick & dirty `*ngIf="router.url.startsWith('/admin')"`

Comment: @phhbr Funny enough I did that 10 seconds before you answered and it worked haha, thank you though!

Answer (score 2):

Using the `router` in the HTML template may not be a good advise. Try putting a variable and use that variable. Something like:

```
dontShowHeader: boolean;

// in ngOnInit or somewhere

ngOnInit() {
  this.dontShowHeader = router.url.startsWith('/admin');
}


// In Template

<header *ngIf="!dontShowHeader">
   Your header Content
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pear, in this case, you will need three things in your project:

1. A service
2. A behavior subject
3. Subscribe

First of all, you need to create a service where will have a behavior subject who will control your header.

So you will subscribe the behavior where you are using the header. When you need to stop to show the header you will change the behavior's value.

If you want to see this approach, see this stackblitz: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hz5ofr?file=src/app/opponent-details.component.html)

Comment: Used a .startsWith on the string instead but I will look at these too thank you!